# How can I display a bitmap in Compose Image

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-bitmap, android-image

I have a function that returns a bitmap (which "contains" a QR code) and I wanted to display that bitmap inside an `Image` (composable function) but I didn't find any way to either convert the bitmap into a `ImageBitmap` or just displaying that bitmap.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Based on [this blog post](https://proandroiddev.com/display-map-snapshot-using-jetpack-compose-e3222186a1a5), it should be possible to display a bitmap like this :

```
@Composable
fun BitmapImage(bitmap: Bitmap) {
    Image(
        bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
        contentDescription = "some useful description",
    )
}
```

I haven't tried it out myself, but recently came across the blog post when looking into displaying maps using Jetpack Compose.

Comment: Is calling .asImageBitmap() inside compose bad for performance? Maybe using derivedStateOf is needed?

Answer (score 10):

[Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/) is capable of displaying a `Bitmap` inside `Image`:

```
Image(
    painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(imageBitmap),
    contentDescription = null,
)
```

Comment: ... which was deprecated and now `rememberAsyncImagePainter`should be used (`coil.compose.rememberAsyncImagePainter`)

Comment: what would br the point of using coil if I already have the Bitmap reference?

Answer (score 1):

To sum up and keep answers up to date)

There are several options to display a bitmap in Compose

1. Using Image

   Image(
   bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
   ...)
2. Using Coil AsyncImage

   AsyncImage(model = bitmap,
   ...)

If you have Unsupported bla bla exception when using AsyncImage, check that you are using Bitmap and not ImageBitmap